# Using CASE and COUNT together in SQL Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to write a SQL statement that can return a column indicating three things. The three things are 'An Actual Class', 'Multiple Classes', 'No Classes Selected'. I have used a function to get this for me, but as the table records grew, this method slowed down quite a bit. Can someone show me how this can be done without sacrificing speed when the amount of records grow? I was thinking some type of case can count together, but cannot figure it out.

The data I need returned would look like this.

```
Student         Classes
Bugs Bunny      Multiple Classes
Daffy Duck      Biology 101
Porky Pig       No Classes Selected
```

```
Schema

Student
StudentId int
Name

Class
ClassId int
Name

StudentClass
StudentId
ClassId
```

Comment: Could you edit the question to include schema/base data which corresponds to the output you've provided?

Comment: Can you post the function you're already using (everything's a bit hypothetical without more idea of the table structure)

Comment: Sorry about forgetting the schema. My schema is the same as posted in the first answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another version, very similar to the prior two; fewer joins, and at most one Class will be looked up per student (might make a difference on truly large tables).

```
SELECT
  xx.Name
  ,case xx.ClassCount
     when 0 then 'No Classes Selected'
     when 1 then cl.Name
     else 'Multiple Classes'
   end  Classes
 from (--  Count classes per student
       select
          st.Name
         ,count(sc.ClassId) ClassCount
         ,max(sc.ClassId)   OneClass  --  If a student has one class, this is it
        from Students st
         left outer join StudentClass sc
          on sc.StudentId = st.StudentId
        group by st.Name) xx
  left outer join Classes cl
   on cl.ClassId = xx.OneClass
```

(Can't debug, hopefully no typos...)

(Can't debug, hopefully no *more* typos...)

Comment: I had just gotten the one right above to work, but I will check this one out, as performance can be real big in this area of my app. Thanks.

Comment: On your last line, you have xx.ClassId. That causes 'Invalid Column Name'. I then try to add 'sc.ClassId' to the SELECT after the first FROM, which gets rid of the error. Then when I run it, I get 'invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause'. Was my attempt to fix it incorrect?

Comment: I mis-coded it, and will edit it. That "xx.ClassId" should be "xx.OneClass", since that's the alias assigned to the singleton ClassId within the subquery. (And that's why I put the "can't debug" disclaimer at the end of code samples I can't run myself...)

Comment: Works great! One quick question...I have to do the same thing for another set of tables, but using a location table with the classes. Can I include another case in the same select statement and just modify the tables for it?

Comment: You should be able to do that. The CASE statement is just another column being selected, albeit a complex formula-based one.

Answer (score 0):

Your schema should look like this

```
Student
StudentId int
Name

Class
ClassId int
Name

StudentClass
StudentId
ClassId
```

Then your query would look like:

```
select
   s.Name,
   CASE x.ClassCount when 0 then 'No Classes Selected' when 1 then c.Name else 'Multiple Classes'
from
   Student s
   inner join
(select
   StudentId, count(sc.ClassId) as ClassCount
from
   Student s 
   left outer join StudentClass sc on s.StudentId = sc.StudentId
group by
  s.StudentId) x on s.StudentId = x.StudentId
  left outer join StudentClass sc2 on sc2.StudentId = x.StudentId and x.ClassCount = 1
  left outer join Class c on c.ClassId = sc2.ClassId
```

Comment: Sorry about not adding the schema, but the one you showed is exactly what I have. Unfortunately, I get 'Invalid column name ClassCount'.

Comment: Not sure why. I added the word "as" before naming ClassCount, but it shouldn't matter. Worth trying again.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at using a subquery to get the student id and the class count then lookup again the class name when there's only one, something like:

```
 Select s.Name,  
     Case s.Count
       When 0 Then 'No Classes Selected' 
       When 1 Then c.className 
       Else 'Multiple Classes' 
     End
From (
    select s.id, s.name, count(cs.id) as Count
    From student s 
    left join studentclass cs on c.studentid = s.id
    group by s.id, s.name
) as s
left join studentclass cs on c.studentid = s.id
left join class c on c.id = cs.classid
```

Of course im old school, the subquery could be factored out into a common table expression (CTE).

Comment: This won't work because you can't select ClassId in the same statement that you are grouping only by name.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use the stack, but this is drastically easier.

```
count(case when field='411' then 1 else null end) as cnt_411
```

Most of these are wrong. The reason is that `COUNT` will return the number of rows when NOT TRUE.

For example:

```sql
WHERE student=123
```

If the student has no classes this semester, it will return all the other rows by count. Count appears to work until it doesn't.

Either use:

```
sum(case when)
```

or

```sql
count(case when else null)
```